# SQL Server Multiple Count and One Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables: Systemuser, Activitypointer and new_TroubleticketTracking.
I want to get the count of activitypointer and count of troubletickettracking grouping by username.

I succeeded in using count and group by for two tables. Here's my code:

```
Select dbo.SystemUser.FullName as [Helpdesk],
       COUNT(dbo.ActivityPointer.OwnerIdName) AS [Activity Related] 
from   dbo.SystemUser 
INNER JOIN dbo.ActivityPointer 
        ON dbo.SystemUser.SystemUserId = dbo.ActivityPointer.OwnerId 
group by dbo.SystemUser.FullName
```

The result:

---

```
Helpdesk|  Activity Related
a       |        10
b       |         5
```

But i am unable to add count for the 3rd table. I tried something like this:

```
Select dbo.SystemUser.FullName as [Helpdesk],
       COUNT(dbo.ActivityPointer.OwnerIdName) AS [Activity Related],
       COUNT(dbo.new_troubletickettracking.OwnerIdName) AS [Test]
from   dbo.SystemUser 
INNER JOIN dbo.ActivityPointer 
        ON dbo.SystemUser.SystemUserId = dbo.ActivityPointer.OwnerId 
INNER JOIN dbo.new_troubletickettracking 
        ON dbo.SystemUser.SystemUserId = dbo.new_troubletickettracking.OwnerId 
group by dbo.SystemUser.FullName
```

But the result is chaos. I want the result lookink like:

```
Helpdesk|  Activity Related  | Troube Ticket
a       |        10          |     20  
b       |         5          |     15
```

Comment: *the result is chaos* = a multiple of the previous numbers? There are multiple rows for each user in both table you join resulting in more rows than expected. You can either use `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` or do the counts on the individual tables in Derived Tables/Common Table Expressions and join the results.

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you could post sample data, expected and actual results. Ideally as a SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

*the result is chaos* = a multiple of the previous numbers?

There are multiple rows for each user in both tables your join results in more rows than expected.

You can either use `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`:

```
Select dbo.SystemUser.FullName as [Helpdesk],
       COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.ActivityPointer.OwnerIdName) AS [Activity Related],
       COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.new_troubletickettracking.OwnerIdName) AS [Test]
from   dbo.SystemUser 
INNER JOIN dbo.ActivityPointer 
        ON dbo.SystemUser.SystemUserId = dbo.ActivityPointer.OwnerId 
INNER JOIN dbo.new_troubletickettracking 
        ON dbo.SystemUser.SystemUserId = dbo.new_troubletickettracking.OwnerId 
group by dbo.SystemUser.FullName
```

Assuming that your join is on PK-FK relations you better do the counts on the individual tables in Derived Tables/Common Table Expressions and join the results. This will be more efficient:

```
Select su.FullName as [Helpdesk],
       ar.[Activity Related],
       tt.[Test]
from   dbo.SystemUser AS su
INNER JOIN
 (
   SELECT OwnerId,
      -- do you really need COUNT(OwnerIdName) instead of COUNT(*)?
      COUNT(OwnerIdName) AS [Activity Related]
   FROM dbo.ActivityPointer 
   GROUP BY OwnerId
 ) AS ar
ON su.SystemUser.SystemUserId = ar.OwnerId 
INNER JOIN
 (
   SELECT OwnerId,
      COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.new_troubletickettracking.OwnerIdName) AS [Test]
   FROM dbo.new_troubletickettracking 
   GROUP BY OwnerId 
 ) AS tt
ON su.SystemUser.SystemUserId = tt.OwnerId
```

Comment: I mean chaos is the result for both column is same with a strange number.  The actual count of ownerid is 25. but the result for both column is 550.

Comment: Yes i do need to count the owneridname.  So i know how much activity created by each user.

Comment: @FikriHailal: I don't know about the relationship between `OwnerIdName` and `OwnerId`, but it sounds like a denormalized table and then `COUNT(*) is the same. Btw, check @dee.ronin answer, it's the same as #2 with Outer Joins, but looks cleaner.

Comment: This is from dynamics crm database.  Ownerid is stored with number.  As a primarykey if the table.  And owneridname is stored with the name values.  like : brian,  adam,  and etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub query for this like the query below:

```
SELECT
    [Helpdesk] = su.FullName,
    [Activity Related] = (SELECT COUNT(ap.OwnerIdName) FROM dbo.ActivityPointer ap WHERE ap.OwnerId = su.SystemUserId ),
    [Test] = (SELECT COUNT(tt.OwnerIdName) FROM dbo.new_troubletickettracking tt WHERE tt.OwnerId = su.SystemUserId )
FROM
    dbo.SystemUser su
```

Comment: You need to mention group by when you are using count function.

Comment: @john, you can use aggregate function even without group by.

Comment: sorry I didn't seen the entire code, yes you are correct

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Sample Data

```
Table1(Name: Tab1)
======
ID            Name
1           srinath
2           srinath1
3           srinath2

Table2(Name: Tab2)
======
userid      name
1           srinath
1           srinath
2           srinath1
2           srinath1
2           srinath1
2           srinath1

Table3(Name: Tab3)
======
userid      name    
1           srinath
2           srinath1
3           srinath2
3           srinath2
3           srinath2
3           srinath2
3           srinath2
3           srinath2
```

Below is the Query

```
;with cte as
(select * from Tab1),
cte1 as (select userid,count(userid) as cnt from Tab2 group by userid),
cte2 as (select userid,count(userid) as cnt from Tab3 group by userid)
select cte.id,cte.name,cte1.cnt,cte2.cnt from cte left join cte1 on cte.id = cte1.userid left join cte2 on cte.id = cte2.userid
```

**Out Put is**

```
 UserID    Name        Cnt1   Cnt2
    1     srinath       2       1
    2     srinath1      4       1
    3      srinath2     NULL    6
```

Below is the Query with your Actual Table Names

```
;with cte as
(select * from SystemUser),
cte1 as (select OwnerId,count(OwnerId) as cnt from ActivityPointer group by OwnerId),
cte2 as (select OwnerId,count(OwnerId) as cnt from new_troubletickettracking group by OwnerId)
select cte.FullName as [Helpdesk],cte1.cnt,cte2.cnt from cte left join cte1 on cte.SystemUserId = cte1.OwnerId left join cte2 on cte.SystemUserId = cte2.OwnerId
```

Just copy above query and execute, you will get the desired out put.

Comment: Is that your full query?  looks like you query is cut in the middle of the script.

Comment: No it is full query, Just modify table names and column names, you can get the out put you want

Comment: @ Fikri Hailal, I modified my answer with actual table names, so that you can just copy and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as
(select * from SystemUser),
cte1 as (select OwnerId,count(OwnerId) as cnt from ActivityPointer group by OwnerId),
cte2 as (select OwnerId,count(OwnerId) as cnt from new_troubletickettracking group by OwnerId)
select cte.FullName as [Helpdesk],cte1.cnt [Activity Related],cte2.cnt [Test] from cte left join cte1 on cte.SystemUserId = cte1.OwnerId left join cte2 on cte.SystemUserId = cte2.OwnerId
```